# How to Write subquery in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, subquery, laravel-query-builder

```
$get_duplicate=DB::select('select * from student_info a join ( select first_name, last_name, dob  from student_info group by first_name, last_name, dob having count(*) > 1 ) b on a.first_name = b.first_name and a.last_name = b.last_name and a.dob = b.dob join participant_info on participant_info.id = a.participant_id order by a.first_name ASC');
```

how to convert this query in Eloquent format.

This is my Model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StudentInfo extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'student_info';
    protected $guarded = array();
    public function student_participant_det(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\ParticipantInfo', 'id','participant_id');

    }
}
```

please help me to convert it in Eloquent format

Comment: Let's see your model's and their associated relationships.

Comment: 'StudentInfo' is a model and 

<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StudentInfo extends Model
{
    //
    public $timestamps = true;
 protected $table = 'student_info';
 protected $guarded = array();
    public function student_participant_det(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\ParticipantInfo', 'id','participant_id');
  
    }
i can get the associated participant information with this function

Comment: Please put any pertinent code in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: hay now can u help me ??

Comment: Can you show `ParticpantInfo` as well please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the previous code. Please Try this.

```
$get_duplicate=DB::table('student_info as a')
->join(DB::raw('(SELECT first_name, last_name, dob  FROM student_info group by first_name, last_name, dob having count(*) > 1 b'), function($join) {
    $join->on('a.first_name', '=', 'b.first_name');
    $join->on('a.last_name', '=', 'b.last_name');
    $join->on('a.dob', '=', 'b.dob'); })
->join('participant_info','participant_info.id', '=', 'a.participant_id')
->orderBy('a.first_name', 'ASC') ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @mith i have figure out the solution .... Thanks For the Help :)